# Replace outlier values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe `input_file`, where I have a column `days.to.play`. Now, I want to remove outlier from this column and replace with median value.

I have created a list containing `days.to.play` values and then used the below function to detect and remove outliers, but none sure, how to substitute outliers with median.

```py
column = input_file['days.to.play']

def reject_outliers(data):
    u = np.mean(data)
    s = np.std(data)
    filtered = [e for e in data if (u - 2 * s < e < u + 2 * s)]
    return filtered

filtered_days = reject_outliers(column name)
```

Comment: Hi jeppe, thanks for the response, however I did not quite get this? Can you please explain how should I use above line of code to replace outliers with median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it into `list`.

Use:

```
u = np.mean(input_file['days.to.play'])
s = np.std(input_file['days.to.play'])
f1 = u - 2*s
f2 = u + 2*s

input_file['days.to.play'] = np.where(input_file['days.to.play'].between(f1,f2),
                            input_file['days.to.play'], input_file['days.to.play'].median())
```

**Explanation**

`np.where` takes first argument as a condition in your case it is Value between `f1` and `f2` and if it is True then it keeps the current value which is `input_file['days.to.play']` else it replaces with median of that column.

Refer [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: Thanks Akshay, it works perfect, just nt sure how last 2 lines of code working.

Answer (score 0):

You can either alter your list-comprehension:

```
median = np.median(data)
filtered = [e if (u - 2 * s < e < u + 2 * s) else median for e in data]
```

Or update directly if data is `numpy.array`:

```
median = np.median(data)
data[u - 2 * s < data < u + 2 * s] = median
```

Here only entries where the expresion `u - 2 * s < data[i] < u + 2 * s` returns true are updated. See an example of updating all even numbers in an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> l[l % 2 == 0] = -1
>>> l
array([ 1, -1,  3, -1,  5, -1])
```

Comment: Great..Thanks Jeppe

Comment: @Saurabh No problem, feel free to accept one of the answers if it solved your problem. :-)